# Найдите количество различных неориентированных связанных графов на четырех различных вершинах

Tags: алгоритм, математика, графы, информатика

Найдите количество различных неориентированных связанных графов на четырех различных вершинах. Например, для трех вершин таких графов четыре.

Как решить поставленную задачу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Открываем [*Введение в теорию графов*](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-907144-75-0.html) на стр. 213 и в таблице обнаруживаем, что связанных простых графов с 4 вершинами - 6 (но вот для трех вершин их только 2).

Естественно, с точностью до изоморфизма. А на странице 25 они все и изображены:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же изоморфизм не учитывать, то... Можно посмотреть теорию [здесь](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/counting_connected_graphs) и на картинке ниже.

Программка в 30 строк для небольших N дает

```
1               1
2               1
3               4
4              38
5             728
6           26704
```

что сразу выводит нас на [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001187) и таблицу побольше :)

```
0       1
1       1
2       1
3       4
4       38
5       728
6       26704
7       1866256
8       251548592
9       66296291072
10      34496488594816
11      35641657548953344
12      73354596206766622208
13      301272202649664088951808
14      2471648811030443735290891264
15      40527680937730480234609755344896
16      1328578958335783201008338986845427712
```

Обещанная теория:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "(но вот для трех вершин их только 2)." а как так если в условии их 4?

Comment: и по этой формуле если считать то совсем другое: Gn=2 * n(n-1)/2=2* 3(3-1)/2=6
а в условии задачи 4

Comment: Мне казалось, что я уже все расписал до последней буквы. И дал ответ - 38. И эта формула, что вы приводите, всего лишь кусочек большего решения. Перечитайте **ВСЁ** еще раз.

Comment: почему ответ 38?

Comment: упс))все заметил)

Comment: а можно эту программку в 30 строк?

Comment: Тю, опять наново писать... Ну простой же рекурсивный вызов...

Comment: Ладно, написал. Работает до 11, дальше переполнения... https://ideone.com/tzc1P0

Answer (score 1):

График с N вершинами может иметь до N*(N-1)/2 ребер (если циклы не допускаются).

Таким образом, общее число возможных графиков равно 2^(N*(N-1)/2).

Comment: то есть раз у нас 4 вершины мы должны подставить вместо N=4?

Comment: мне кажется неверна формула так как по примеру даже не получается
подставим N=3
2^3=8
 а там 4 графа а не 8

Comment: вы может разъясните ?

Comment: пожалуйста напишите пояснение

Comment: Этот ответ не учитывает связность.